# Apache NTFS symlink linux

Tags: apache-http-server, ntfs, symbolic-link

I have a dualboot system with a common NTFS drive. I wish to store my files there and run from there. I ran into several roadblocks and cleared most of them. Here is what I am facing.

I have set my document root to this ntfs folder. When I run localhost i get forbidden error.Apache throws this error.

```
access to / denied (filesystem path '/media/Web') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Comment: Could you paste the output of `ls -l /var/www/html/Work` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is one of the folder in the hierarchy didnt have execute permission